# Firebase Auth Import SHA256 Hash: Can't login with password after import

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to migrate users (using firebase-admin@8.13.0) into firebase auth, following this guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_md5_sha_and_pbkdf_hashed_passwords

In the old system, the passwords were hashed in php:

```
$Password = hash('sha256', $Password);
```

I'm running this code to import the users into firebase:

```
const res = await admin.auth().importUsers([{
  uid: 'ABC123',
  email: 'tester@test.com',
  passwordHash: Buffer.from('5457ae6b180556bc65b423ba3a36124ec44f6cbec7da84e483daa2a46dec3f97') 
}], {
  hash: {
    algorithm: 'SHA256',
    rounds: 1
  }
});
```

The import succeeds, but I can't login using the same password (LeeT1337).

Also when I export all users, running

```
firebase auth:export auth-export.json --format json
```

the imported user, unlike all others, doesn't have a `passwordHash` property.

I've also tried base64-encoding the hash first (since it's suggested in old stack posts, but not in the docs anymore).

Alternativlely I've tried importing via the cli (firebase-tools@8.13.1) with:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": "ABC123",
      "email": "tester@test.com",
      "passwordHash": "NTQ1N2FlNmIxODA1NTZiYzY1YjQyM2JhM2EzNjEyNGVjNDRmNmNiZWM3ZGE4NGU0ODNkYWEyYTQ2ZGVjM2Y5Nw=="
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
firebase auth:import users-for-import.json --hash-algo=SHA256 --rounds=1
```

but got the same result: Import works, login doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Buffer.from('5457ae6b180556bc65b423ba3a36124ec44f6cbec7da84e483daa2a46dec3f97')
```

needs to be changed to

```
Buffer.from('5457ae6b180556bc65b423ba3a36124ec44f6cbec7da84e483daa2a46dec3f97', 'hex')
```